# JQuery .when not working outside of code block

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently playing around with the Beaker Browser API and I need to make several ( atleast 20 ) ajax requests to another user's website in order to get what they have posted.

I have the following arrays:

```
var posts = []; // Where the data of the ajax is stored
var ajax_requests = []; // Where the ajax requests are stored
var following = []; // Where the urls for all requests are
```

And the following logic looping through all links

```
// Get posts from all the people you follow
for(var i = 0; i < following.length; i++) {

    // Get the person's url and folders
    let person = new DatArchive(following[i]);

    // Read the directory containing all the posts
    person.readdir("/posts").then(files => {

        // For each post
        for(var j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
            // Request the JSON object representing that post and add it to the array
            ajax_requests.push(get_posts(person.url + "/posts/" + files[j]));
        }
    });
}
```

The get_posts() function and the .when:

```
function get_posts(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Adding to posts");
            posts.push(data);
        }
    });
}    



$.when.apply($, ajax_requests).then(function() {
    console.log(posts.length);
});
```

What I am trying to understand is why the `$.when` is not waiting for the ajax to finish. I thought that's what it was supposed to do, instead it returns the empty array. That's the one, the other is why it works if I move it inside the `person.readdir("/posts")` block.

I can't just leave it in there since the logic I want to go inside needs to sort the posts array and only display a portion of it, I don't think that should be something that runs more than once a page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.map()` and `$.when.apply()` pattern twice to await all results from inner loop

```js
let following = [1, 2, 3];

function get_posts(url) {
    return new $.Deferred(dfd => 
      setTimeout(dfd.resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), url));
}  

$.when.apply($
, $.map(following, (follower) => {
    let person = new $.Deferred(dfd => 
                   setTimeout(dfd.resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
                   , Array(3).fill(follower))
                 );
  return person
         .then(files => 
           $.when.apply($
           , $.map(files, (file) => 
               get_posts("/posts/" + file)))
         )
}))
.then(function(...data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `ajax_requests` array `.length` is equal to `following.length` multiplied by `files.length` before calling `$.when.apply()`

```js
var following = [1, 2, 3];
var ajax_requests = [];

function get_posts(url) {
  return $.Deferred(dfd => 
    setTimeout(dfd.resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), url));
}

for (var i = 0; i < following.length; i++) {

  // Get the person's url and folders
  let person = new $.Deferred(dfd => 
                 setTimeout(dfd.resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
                 , Array(3).fill(following[i]))
               );

  // Read the directory containing all the posts
  person.then(files => {

    // For each post
    for (var j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
      // Request the JSON object representing that post and add it to the array
      ajax_requests.push(get_posts("/posts/" + files[j]));
      if (ajax_requests.length === following.length * files.length) {
        $.when.apply($, ajax_requests).then(function(...data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: The if statement doesn't seem to run, everything below and above runs but the if skips.

Comment: @alexHexan What do you mean by "doesn't seem to run"? The pattern at stacksnippets is the same pattern at code at Question. The resulting array at `.then()` chained to `$.when()` at stacksnippets contains the resolved values of the jQuery promise object. You should probably include error handling within the code. If any of the jQuery promise objects throws an error `.then()` chained to `$.when()` will not be reached.

Comment: It wasn't working because the different person objects do not contain the same amount of files, my question was flawed.

Comment: @alexHexan You can use approach at other Answer, which does not check the `.length` of the array